# Identify if a list of time series is equal to another list of time series

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have two list: `list_1` and `list_2` the elements of each one are timeseries. Time series en `list_1` may or may not be in `list_2`. Time series in both list looks like this:

```
2007-07-03 1270.9060
2007-07-04 1267.8440
2007-07-05 1269.7260
2007-07-06 1270.7180
2007-07-07 1270.6210
2007-07-08 1270.5230
2007-07-09 1272.6600
2007-07-10 1275.3270
2007-07-11 1269.2300
2007-07-12 1267.7230
2007-07-13 1271.5470
2007-07-14 1271.4500
2007-07-15 1271.3520
2007-07-16 1271.2550
2007-07-17 1269.3970
2007-07-18 1258.4610
2007-07-19 1259.3700
2007-07-20 1272.2220
2007-07-21 1272.1250
2007-07-22 1272.0270
2007-07-23 1279.5210
2007-07-24 1283.7750
2007-07-25 1292.8030
2007-07-26 1279.0540
```

I need two things:

1. Identify which time series are in one list that are not in the other, for that, I use this code:

   ```
   names1 = sort(names(list_1))
    names2 = sort(names(list_2))
    c(setdiff(names1,names2),setdiff(names2,names1))
   ```
2. For the names of the time series that are in both list, I need to identify if the two respective time series are identical. For this I used this code:

quantq = list()

```
for (i in names1) {
  if (i %in% names(2)) {
    quantq[i] = names(all(list_1[[i]] != list_2[[i]]))
  }
  }
```

I created the list quantq that hopefully contains the names of the time series in `names1` that are not identical to its equivalent in `names2`, but unfortunallly it seems not to work because it gives me something like this:

```
   [1]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
  [19]   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36
  [37]   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54
  [55]   55   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72
  [73]   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89   90
  [91]   91   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108
 [109]  109  110  111  112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119  120  121  122  123  124  125  126
 [127]  127  128  129  130  131  132  133  134  135  136  137  138  139  140  141  142  143  144
 [145]  145  146  147  148  149  150  151  152  153  154  155  156  157  158  159  160  161  162
```

I think that the problem is that my code takes only one list and shows  the number of the entries that are not equal in the respective timeseries of each list. Am I right?.

Can you gys help me to create the list with the names of the time series that are not identical?

Here, I present A small subset of the two list: `ex1` for `list_1`
`ex2` for `list_2`:

```
ex1 = list(COP = structure(c(1877.5, 1892.5, 1910, 1912.4, 1901, 1902.5, 
1901, 1905.85, 1917, 1921), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(946857600, 
946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 947548800, 
947635200, 947721600, 947808000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L)), CLP = structure(c(528, 529.43, 530, 527, 524.55, 522.5, 
522.5, 519.53, 517.05, 515.67), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(946857600, 
946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 947548800, 
947635200, 947721600, 947808000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L)), CLF = structure(c(0.036074341203342, 0.0358335681613619, 
0.0360059735494465, 0.0358781557617286, 0.035702777866953, 0.0356677208908729, 
0.0355560203401352, 0.035958251000177, 0.035870302585323, 0.0357348617586791
), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1080864000, 1081123200, 
1081209600, 1081296000, 1081382400, 1081728000, 1081814400, 1081900800, 
1081987200, 1082073600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL)))

ex2 = list(CLP = structure(c(528, 529.43, 530, 527, 524.55, 522.5, 
522.5, 519.53, 517.05, 515.67), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(946857600, 
946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 947548800, 
947635200, 947721600, 947808000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L)), CLF = structure(c(0.036074341203342, 0.0358335681613619, 
0.0360059735494465, 0.0358781557617286, 0.035702777866953, 0.0356677208908729, 
0.0355560203401352, 0.035958251000177, 0.035870302585323, 0.0357348617586791
), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1080864000, 1081123200, 
1081209600, 1081296000, 1081382400, 1081728000, 1081814400, 1081900800, 
1081987200, 1082073600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL)), MXN = structure(c(9.505, 
9.5713, 9.571, 9.58, 9.565, 9.47, 9.5125, 9.522, 9.4875, 9.4503
), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(946857600, 946944000, 
947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 947548800, 947635200, 
947721600, 947808000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L)), PEN = structure(c(3.52, 3.5205, 3.519, 3.509, 3.511, 3.509, 
3.508, 3.509, 3.5005, 3.4875), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(946857600, 
946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 947548800, 
947635200, 947721600, 947808000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L)))
```

Comment: Will you please (a) shorten your example to make it more minimal---this will make it clearer, and (b) share the sample data with `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable including all class and structure information. E.g., `dput(list_1[1:10])` and `dput(list_2[1:10])` for the first 10 rows.

Comment: dput(list_1[1:10]) will give the first 10 rows of every time serie in list_1? If it is, it is still a really big dataset, because each list has more than 1000 time series and each time series has more tha 3000 observations (rows). How can I give a more simple example

Comment: Ah, okay `dput(lapply(list_1[1:3],  head, 10)` will give the first 10 rows of each of the first 3 times series in `list_1`. Pick a suitable small subset that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added the small subset of my dataset

Comment: What is `series_list_manual` and `series_list_s3` refer to ?

Comment: My bad... It is already edited in the question

Answer (score 0):

Update: I think I manage to solve the problem. This is what I attempted:

```
names1 = sort(names(list_1))  #To obtain the names of the timeseries in list_1
names2 = sort(names(list_2))  #To obtain the names of the timeseries in list_2
not_eq = c(setdiff(names1,names2),setdiff(names2,names1)) #This gives the names of the timeseries that are not in the intersection of the lists
(length(names1))
(length(names2))


quantq = list() #I created an empty list to storage the name of the timeseries that are not identical in the two lists


for (tik in names1){
  if (tik %in% names2 & !identical(list_1[[tik]], list_2[[tik]])){
    quantq[[tik]] = tik
    print(which(list_1[[tik]] != list_2[[tik]]))
   }else {
    print("Equal")
   }
  }

names(quantq)  #To get the names of the unequal timeseries
(length(names(quantq))) #To verify the unequal time series are less or equal than the total
```

What do you guys think? Can it be improved?